# phpMailer Windows Azure and Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, azure, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I got today access to a client's server where i deployed an application that i made, using TeamViewer and a Virtual Machine Apparently on Windows Server 2008 R2 (what a headache), So the IT guys don't have a clue on how to setup an SMTP server.

So i set up one Gmail account to use with the Aplication, on my local machine everything works just fine with the emails.

even

```
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
    $mail->Port = 587;
    //Or
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
```

Does not really matter in that cloud server, Gmail itself keeps blocking the access from that account because the server is located in Switzerland and i usually log that account on Venezuela, so Far i have told Gmail in [this url](http://google.com/blocked) that i'm the one accessing, but it keeps blocking all my attempts.

Any workaround to this?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly is it blocking? What do you see if you set `SMTPDebug = 4`?

Comment: Gmail itself, i noticed because i got a text message on my cellphone, then on gmail.com/blocked it appears as the access was blocked. haven't tried that yet give me a chance and i'll report back.